# Should I use the NgZone class?

Tags: angular, zonejs

In AngularJS 2, most zone-related examples and articles center on the `zone` object and functions like `zone.fork` and `zone.run`. For example, this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9Bbp6Hh2YE) focus on the `zone` object.

But the AngularJS 2 [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html) presents a class named NgZone. I'd like to use methods like `onTurnStart` and `onTurnDone`, but I can't find any examples of these methods being used. Should I bother using this class at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular2 the NgZone class is a wrapper around the zone.js framework. Also the dependency injector will pass in the `zone` that relates to that component.

So the answer is: If you are going to use `zone` at all. Then definitely use `NgZone`.

The documentation for NgZone can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html) including all of the methods and their arguments.

Comment: I see that, but there's just so much documentation and example code available for zone and almost nothing for NgZone. If no one else is using NgZone, why should I?

Comment: `NgZone == zone` essentially. You can use the docs for `zone` in conjunction with `NgZone` provided that the method exposed is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but the only method they have in common is run. And the Angular2 documentation doesn't explain what a microtask is or show how onTurnStart/onTurnDone/onEventDone are expected to be used. I'll stick with zone for now, and use NgZone when there's more (some) documentation.

Comment: @user934904 check this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) from Pascal Precht. Note as well that Zone was proposed to TC39, see this [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H3E2ToJ8VHgZS8eS6bRv-vg5OksObj5wv6gyzJJwOK0/edit#slide=id.g105c754704_1_55) (sadly just slides, no video)

Comment: @Eric, thanks. I read the article and the presentation, but neither mention the NgZone class and its methods. I'd like to know if there's a way to fork a new zone from an NgZone, but it looks like you need zone.fork.

Comment: ^^ I'm wondering the same thing @user934904. Did you ever figure it out?